Native app using GitHub OAuth - is a server necessary?
I've been writing a GitHub client app that at the moment simply uses PATs (Personal Access Tokens) generated by GitHub
I'd like to expand this app to use GitHub OAuth which is more user friendly so people don't have to go in and generate those PATs
On reading through the docs it looks like I need to host a server for this OAuth to work - which seems overly complex given how thin this layer will need to be (mainly in the expense of setting up and hosting a server just for a callback URL)
Is this needed? Or is there a way to setup GitHub OAuth without the need for a backend server?
